Did Einstein say the one-way speed-of-light is "not a fact of nature"?
If so is there a published paper where he said as much?

It doesn't sound like the kind of phrase one would use in a published paper. If he ever said anything along those lines, be it in English or German, I imagine what he meant was it's not empirically verifiable. But I also expect he'd believe in a one-way speed of light.

This is not a physics question, it is a history question. Try here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Einstein spends considerable time at the start of his early SR papers (& popular book) clearly detailing his clock synchronisation procedure. This procedure assumes that the one-way speed equals the round-trip speed. A few years later, Hans Reichenbach made it explicit that a whole family of synchronisation conventions are possible which preserve the round-trip speed. See https://sites.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_conv_sim/index.html especially Reichenbach's ε

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on hsm.stackexchange .

Don't disagree.  I reposted it on the hsm page

I concur with the comment stating that this is a question for the History of Science and Mathematics stackexchange.
In the specific case of Einstein:
There is the Einstein Papers project. Not only is all of Einstein's correspondence published in those volumes, the content is machine searcheable.
In 2020 I answered a question on whether Einstein had at some point indicated that in hindsight the name 'Theory of invariants' (or 'Invariance theory') would have been a better name, instead of 'Special relativity'.
Einstein: 'SR is a theory of invariants, not relativity' -- source?
I include the link to show just how much is possible.
